# Which of these is right?

Tags: grammar, commas

I have three sentences here, and I'm not sure of which one to use.

1

> She walked home, and slept immediately after.

2

> She walked home, and she slept immediately after.

3

> She walked home and slept immediately after.

Thanks, I appreciate the help.

Comment: Use whichever you want.

Comment: which is most right then?

Comment: Number 2 and 3 are both correct, 3 is the most natural, as noted in my answer.

Comment: "Most right" depends on things like style or what you want to emphasise or personal preference ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Number 1 is incorrect. Number 3 is the most natural.

A simple comma rule for "and" is that if you say both subjects (even if they're the same), you need a comma. If you only have one subject, you shouldn't use a comma. For example:

> I went home, and I ate ice cream.
>
> I went home and ate ice cream.

Both are correct, though we'd probably use the second one because it's easier.

Comment: What is wrong with no 1? It seems OK to me...

Comment: First one is incorrect? That means "and" can't be preceded by a comma?

Comment: If "and" doesn't link two independent clauses (complete SVO) it should not use a comma, unless part of a list (and that one depends on your style guide). Random source: https://www.businessinsider.com/a-guide-to-proper-comma-use-2013-9

Comment: I've just read the Wikipedia article on commas about this. Are you sure this rule isn't based on each style guide? Wikipedia says some style guides prescribe that the comma be removed before the conjunction and dependent clause.

Comment: @Zebrafish Yes, the *dependent* clause. Two independent clauses (I like cats. She likes dogs.) require a comma when connected (I like cats, and she likes dogs.). A dependent clause (because they're cute) does not require a comma unless it appears before the independent clause (I like cats because they are cute. -or- Because they are cute, I like cats.)

Comment: Now you say the comma's not necessary, whereas in your last comment you said it can't be there, which is why you said the first sentence is incorrect. Even assuming the rule we're talking about here is that the comma can't be there before the conjunction and dependent clause, I'm still asking isn't this rule still based on each style guide? I've read the Wikipedia article on commas and it says that some style guides require that the comma be removed.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify, by "doesn't require" I mean "shouldn't be there". Looking at the wiki article, it says that "some style guides" require a that there *be* a comma before an independent clause, and that there *not be* a comma before a dependent one (exactly as I said), but does not make any reference to which style guides disagree, or what they say. For example, the Oxford style guide doesn't say you shouldn't use a comma before a dependent clause, but that's because they don't say when you *shouldn't*, only when you should (with everything else implied to be "shouldn't").

Comment: That sounds like an awfully strange understanding to me, that when the Oxford style guide is silent on a particular use of a comma that it's to be taken as prohibited. Maybe I can make this particular rule the subject of a question of my own, as I am rather interested in knowing whether the first example in the OPs question is in fact incorrect. It's clearly proscribed by some style guides, but i don't have access to any of my own to check for myself, apart from website articles.

Comment: Also, isn't the matter of what a style guide prescribes quite different from the grammar? In that respect I don't understand to what extent the first sentence is incorrect English.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81766/discussion-between-drazex-and-zebrafish).

Comment: There is nothing actually ungrammatical about #1. Although less common than normal, it's purely a matter of style. There is no dependent clause; there are two independent clauses (the second with the pronoun elided) joined by a conjunction. There is also an unnecessary but not incorrect comma thrown in.

Comment: There are *not* two independent clauses. This is a parallel verb. Using a comma between two elements of a parallel structure *is incorrect*. It is explicitly proscribed by the AP Style manual, and I would challenge you to find a style guide that explicitly allows it. From the AP Style guide: "When not to use a comma:
Before the word "and" when it connects two parallel elements"  http://www.apsstylemanual.org/oldmanual/mechanics/commas.htm

Comment: Commas serve two purposes, and sometimes those purposes may conflict with each other. A comma can be a grammatical feature, but also can be an indication of a pause. #1 is quite correct, all the style guides in the universe notwithstanding, if, and only if, the writer intended the reader to hear a pause.

Comment: One should only violate the rules of punctuation for emphasis if one knows exactly what they are, and the *artistic* license does not apply to formal writing, where style guides should always be followed, or even general writing, where they are best practice. Given the OP is asking for which one they should use, clearly they are looking for the *most correct* choice (and even clarified that this is what they were looking for), which is the one that adheres to the style guides.